# Is there a Word to describe Words that have Differing Masculine and Feminine Forms?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-positive

Granted that English has few such words, blond/blonde and fiancé/fiancée are the only ones that immediately come to mind. Apart from calling them "words with gender-specific forms", the closest I've come up with is [epicenitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicenity), which isn't even a real form of the word, or possibly [androgynous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/androgynous). And either of these seem to convey something that's the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: English has plenty of "gendered" words (police*man*, chair*woman*, bar*maid*, school*boy*).  But I hesitate to post "gendered" as an answer, since "gendered language" also means "reflecting the experience, prejudices, or orientations of one sex more than the other" (*M-W*)

Comment: 'Gender-differentiated' words. See [Quizlet.com](https://quizlet.com/291890389/words-differentiated-by-gender-flashcards/)

Comment: @NigelJ, it's as close as anything I've been able to come up with.  In my mind, I'm looking for a single word that ends in -nym, -ic or -ical like "demonym" or "radical". Or a non-English word that has no English equivalent owning to the disuse of the practice in English.

Comment: Yes; your suggestions don't fit. 'Lacuna' means 'a lexical gap; the lack of a potentially useful word in a language, where one might be expected to exist (there might be an equivalent in say Polish)'. //// The blond/blonde distinction is probably being lost, especially with the adjective and especially in the US.

Comment: Certainly not *androgynous*; that means gender-ambiguous, the opposite of what these words are.

Comment: The blonde and fiance distinctions are no longer there. Only some writers make the distinction, which is not made in speech, and only some editors let them get away with it. Forget about that. Do you mean a "word" like _Latinx_? (I always hear "latinks" when I see that). I would say it's involved with gender, but not in any simple way. Then there's _actor/tress_ and _maestro/a._

Answer (score 2):

They're sometimes called **gender-marked words** (or expressions):

> In the English language, there are approximately 385 male gender-marked words and only 132 female gender-marked words. [...] A frequently noted example is the difference in connotation between the phrases *bull session*, which is male-marked, and *hen party*, which is female-marked.
>
> — [The Interpretation of Generic Language as Male or Male/Female
> by Nine and Ten Year Old Children](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3088&context=masters_theses)

Answer (score 0):

Such words are often called **gendered,** defined [by Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gendered) as:

> characteristic of, suited to, or biased toward one gender

One should note that this meaning is not related to grammatical gender.

Answer (score -2):

You could also say "have grammatical gender"

Comment: That isn't what grammatical gender is. Nouns in English don't have grammatical gender.

Comment: Yeah, it's not grammatical gender. An example of [grammatical gender](https://cpercy.artsci.utoronto.ca/courses/6361ArchibaldBarber.htm) would be "se wifmann", since it takes the masculine determiner "se". That's Old English for "the woman"; Modern English doesn't have grammatical gender.